# TSQL or SSIS convert Columns into Rows

Tags: t-sql, ssis

Could anyone please suggest how to achieve the following? i.e. convert columns in to rows using either TSQL or SSIS:

e.g.
from this:

```
col1    col2
start   end
```

to this:

```
start
end
```

from this:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
start   break   start   end
```

to this:

```
start
break
start
break
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Dalex for your answer.

Since I'm using SSIS I ended up using Unpivot Transformation Task which required no code.